# Is it a good practice to use a function within another function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code:

```
public function client() {

    echo "inside client controller";

    function ordersData() {
    
        echo "get clients orders data";
            
    }

    function create() {
    
        echo "creating new client";
            
    }
        
}
```

My call at the URL is

> localhost:8080/app/controller/client

to show

> "inside client controller"

or for example

> localhost:8080/app/controller/client/create

to show

> "creating new client"

.

Is it a good practice?

Comment: No, named functions inside of another named function is not good practice for PHP in general

Comment: @aynber okay thanks, how can I do something like that but using good practice? You know something?

Comment: Just declare three separate functions and call one from another one... Also, any book with PHP basics would be a good investment.

Comment: @biesior thanks, I am a beginner programmer, sorry for the stupid question

Comment: I understand, everybody started some time ago. But there are things that are required to learn at the beginning, not-nesting functions are one of them. If you have no time to get any book please check the internet, there are tons of articles about such things.

Comment: @RaulReis - functions exists under Classes in CodeIgniter. Which version of CI are you using?

Comment: @ChristianBonato CI3, but I already do some tests and my question dont have any sense.